# Radio button and checkbox issues wtih Android webview on Android TV "Nexus Player" DPad

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webview, android-tv, nexus-player

**Nexus Player** comes with **DPad** *(Bluetooth remote controller)*. It's **directional pad** acts like a standard *up/down/left/right* buttons on the keyboard. Thanks to that you can navigate the HTML-written app *(webview)* as from the standard PC/Mac. **DPad** has also a **select button** which is detected by webview as the **Enter** key. Pressing **Enter/Select** key works with standard **buttons** and **a href** links but it does not work with **checkboxes** and **radio buttons**.

[Dpad description](http://www.google.com/design/spec-tv/system-overview/navigation.html#navigation-controllers)

**Radio buttons** and **checkboxes** on the PC change the status only when **Space** key is pressed. Unfortunately, **DPad** does not have the **Space** key. The trick to get this working is:

1. Detect if any key has been pressed: `onkeydown`
2. Detect if Enter/Select key has been pressed: `if(event.keyCode == 13){}`
3. Emulate the click on the checkbox/radio button: `this.click()`
4. Prevent default action which is a submit the form when the Enter/Select is pressed: `event.preventDefault()`

This gives us a simple "hack" written purely in **JavaScript** which works with **AngularJS**: `onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) {this.click(); event.preventDefault()}"`

In my case the **checkbox** element looks like this:

```
<input ng-change="MyFunction()"
       ng-model="MyVariables"
       ng-required="!MyVariables"
       name="MyRadioButton"
       id="MyRadioButton"
       value="MyValue"
       type="radio"
       onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) {this.click(); event.preventDefault()}"/>
```

Note: You could also change the state of the checkbox or radio button with `this.checked` but in my case as I use **AngularJS** this was not working *(ng-change nor ng-click will not notice changes done programmatically to the checkbox/radio button)*.

So, here comes my question. Is there any more "proper" way to achive this?

Comment: There's no better way. Doing anything with WebViews is always going to be some sort of a hack.